# uri format connection gets access-denied in mysql

Tags: mysql2, node-mysql

I'm using Node and MySQL2
`import mysql2 from 'mysql2'`

**Following successfully creates connection:**

```
const connection = mysql2.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: 'My@Password',
        database: 'MyDB',
    })
```

But using the URI format with same attributes throws **Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)**

```
const connection = mysql2.createConnection(
        'mysql://root:My@Password@localhost:3306/MyDB'
    )
```

What is the mistake with URI format?

[UPDATE]
I've tried to encode the @, but it still doesn't works

```
'mysql://root:My%40Password@localhost:3306/MyDB'
```

Is there a method in MySQL library that returns the URI? I can create successful connection using the first approach and see what URI it actually generates.

Comment: The mistake is the unencoded `@` in the password.

Comment: Encoded @ doesn't work too.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot use special characters like '@', ':', '/', in url and you are using '@' in password
Try updating password , that mean without '@' or you need to properly encode the password using the encodeURIComponent function in JavaScript

Comment: I had tried replacing @ with %40, but got the same issue.